# jQuery: Accessing text content of descendant upon clicking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouseevent

```html
<div class="subjects">
  <div class="bg-red">
    <i class="lni lni-rocket"></i>
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Physics</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Say I have the above html, and I would like to get the text content of `h6` every time I click the outermost `div`. Here's what I did:

```js
$('.subjects').on('click', (e) => {
    const h6 = $(this).find('h6');
    console.log(h6.text());
});
```

But this does not print `Physics`, which was inside `h6`. It print's an empty string. How do I access the text of `h6` when I click the outermost `div`?

Comment: In short: `$('.subjects').on('click', function() {...`.

Comment: @Andy Thanks! So just to be clear for anyone who stumbles on this, arrow functions does not have its own `this`. Arrow functions establish `this` based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#:~:text=have%C2%A0their%20own-,this,-.%20Another%20example%20involving)